# error happened when install kivy in my windows 7

Tags: python, installation, kivy

I am trying to install Kivy 1.9.0 into my Python environment (Windows 7+, Python 2.7.8) via 'pip install kivy' command.

I am encountering this error message.  Why?

```
    c:\users\admini~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-mkquri\kivy\kivy\graphics\ope
ngl.c: In function '__pyx_pf_4kivy_8graphics_6opengl_280gl_init_symbols':

    **c:\users\admini~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-mkquri\kivy\kivy\graphics\ope
ngl.c:19046: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 1 of 'PyString_FromStr
ing' differ in signedness
    writing c:\users\admini~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-mkquri\kivy\kivy\grap
hics\opengl.def
    c:\mingw\bin\gcc.exe -shared -s c:\users\admini~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-bui
ld-mkquri\kivy\kivy\graphics\opengl.o c:\users\admini~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-b
uild-mkquri\kivy\kivy\graphics\opengl.def -LC:\Python27\libs -LC:\Python27\PCbui
ld -lopengl32 -lglew32 -lpython27 -lmsvcr90 -o build\lib.win32-2.7\kivy\graphics
\opengl.pyd -lm
    c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.3.3/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot
 find -lglew32
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
     error: command 'c:\\mingw\\bin\\gcc.exe' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
    Command "C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:
\\users\\admini~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-mkquri\\kivy\\setup.py';exec(
compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'),
__file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\admini~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-bk
40dp-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" fa
iled with error code 1 in c:\users\admini~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-mkquri\
kivy

c:\Python27>
```